# PowerShell elseif not reading last function

Tags: powershell

When printing out the function it only prints out the divisible by 3 and 5 but doesn't print out the divisible by 15.

```
function Print-Numbers-Weird ([int]$count) {
    for ($i=1; $i -le $count; $i++) {
        $isdivisibleby3  = $i % 3 -eq 0
        $isdivisibleby5  = $i % 5 -eq 0
        $isdivisibleby15 = $i % 15 -eq 0

        if ($isdivisibleby3) {
            Write-Host $i "- divisibleby3"
        } elseif ($isdivisibleby5) {
            Write-Host $i "- divisibleby5"
        } elseif ($isdivisibleby15) {
            Write-Host $i "- divisibleby15"
        } else {
            Write-Host $i
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Numbers that can be devided by 15 can also be devided by 3, so your code never reaches the `$isdevisibleby15` clause because the `$isdevisibleby3` clause matches first.

Comment: Make the comparisons from largest value to smallest

Comment: You might read this again:  [Fizz Buzz Test](http://wiki.c2.com/?FizzBuzzTest)

Answer (score 2):

[Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

> Numbers that can be divided by `15` can also be divided by `3`, so your code never reaches the `$isdivisibleby15` clause, because the `$isdivisibleby3` clause matches first.

[Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) points out that your question is the PowerShell incarnation of the ["FizzBuzz" job-interview question](http://wiki.c2.com/?FizzBuzzTest), and [UnhandledExcepSean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1007019/unhandledexcepsean) points out that performing the `$isdivisibleby15` test *first* solves your problem.

To solve your problem in a *PowerShell-idiomatic* manner, use a [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch):

```
function Get-WeirdNumbers ([int] $count) {
  switch (1..$count) {
    { $_ % 3 -eq 0 }  { "$_ - divisibleby3" }
    { $_ % 5 -eq 0 }  { "$_ - divisibleby5" }
    { $_ % 15 -eq 0 } { "$_ - divisibleby15" }
    default           { $_ }
  }
}
```

The above solution evaluates *all* conditionals (except that the `default` branch is only executed if *nothing else* matches). This will show you how certain numbers match *multiple* times, namely those that are divisible by *both* 3 and 5, which implies that they're *also* divisible by 15.

---

To solve the "FizzBuzz" problem specifically (print `Fizz` for numbers divisible by `3`, `Buzz` for numbers divisible by `5`, ***or*** `FizzBuzz` for numbers divisible by *both* `3` and `5`, and all other numbers as themselves - i.e., print *one* representation per input number):

- The branches must be arranged to test for divisibility by 15 *first*.
- Processing of the remaining branches must be *skipped*, once a match is found.

```
function Get-FizzBuzz ([int] $count) {
  switch (1..$count) {
    { $_ % 15 -eq 0 } { "FizzBuzz"; continue }
    { $_ % 5 -eq 0 }  { "Buzz"; continue }
    { $_ % 3 -eq 0 }  { "Fizz"; continue }
    default           { $_ }
  }
}
```

Note how `continue` is used to skip processing of the remaining branches.
While `break` is available too, it would skip processing of any remaining input numbers, given that the input is an *array* of numbers.

---

Here's an alternative solution based on a `foreach` loop that again uses conditionals of which *more than one can match*, combined with *string concatenation*, to achieve the desired result:

```
function Get-FizzBuzz ([int] $count) {
  foreach ($num in 1..$count) {
    $output = ''
    if ($num % 5 -eq 0) { $output =  'Fizz' }
    if ($num % 3 -eq 0) { $output += 'Buzz' }
    # Output the result
    if ($output) { $output } else { $num }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution you could use with `if/elseif`

```
1..100 | %{

    $x = $_

    if($x %15 -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Host "fizzbuzz"
    }elseif($x %3 -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Host "fizz"
    }elseif($x %5 -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Host "buzz"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host $x
    }        
}
```

The explanation from mklement0 is absolutely right, though.